# Pyramid Tutorial "wiki" throws NameError on login

Tags: python, pyramid

Following the pyramid wiki tutorial very closely, but I get the following thrown when I actually login as the editor:

```
NameError: logged_in

 - Expression: "logged_in"
 - Filename:   /Users/erik/pyramid/tutorial/tutorial/templates/edit.pt
 - Location:   (line 25: col 23)
 - Source:     <span tal:condition="logged_in">
                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Examining the code I see no mechanism for `logged_in` to have been attached to the request.

Curiously, when I remove `/edit_page` from the URI the Logout link is correctly displayed in the `viewing` template. Baffled, in Vancouver...

Answer (score 3):

`logged_in` isn't part of the request, it's data passed to the template by the edit view. Take a look at lines 72-84 in the tutorial's [view.py](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/1.3-branch/docs/tutorials/wiki/src/authorization/tutorial/views.py):

```python
@view_config(name='edit_page', context='.models.Page',
             renderer='templates/edit.pt',
             permission='edit')
def edit_page(context, request):
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        context.data = request.params['body']
        return HTTPFound(location = request.resource_url(context))

    logged_in = authenticated_userid(request)

    return dict(page = context,
                save_url = request.resource_url(context, 'edit_page'),
                logged_in = logged_in)
```

Here you can see `logged_in` is being set via the `authenticated_userid` call and then passed to the template as part of the dictionary in the return.

Make sure your `edit_page` view is hooked up correctly in the `view_config` and returning `logged_in` as the right name.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  You point to an older version of the tutorial, but I did find my error as a result. I had dropped a paren. I was returning:  return dict(page = context,
                save_url = request.resource_url(context, 'edit_page',logged_in = logged_in))

Comment: That'll do it :) For future questions, it helps if you include a link to the tutorial you're referring to, to avoid my mistake of talking about the wrong one.